# How to replace comma followed multiple spaces and & symbol with & using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

Am trying to replace comma followed by multiple spaces and & symbol with & using php. Is there any way to do it

```
 example: a,     & b.
  expected output: a & b.
```

I have tried but it works for only single space. doesn't work for multiple dynamic spaces. Here is my sample code

```
$var = "a,   & b.";
$var = str_replace(', &','&',$var);
```

Comment: You don't need `str_replace`. Use `preg_replace('~,\s*(\s&)~', '$1', $var);`

Comment: @revo thanks its working

Answer (score 1):

You could use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and match [`, +&`](https://regex101.com/r/Z5vMt4/1) and replace with a whitespace followed by an `&`

That would match a comma, one or more whitespaces `+` followed by an ampersand `&`. To match any horizontal whitespace character you might also use `,\h+&`

```
$var = "a,   & b.";
$var = preg_replace('/, +&/',' &',$var);
echo $var;
```

[Test](https://3v4l.org/g6aMP)